# The datediff function resulted in an overflow message

Tags: sql-server

doing something like this:

```
select * 
from INVOICE_HEADING 
where INVOICE_DATE >=  '06 Dec 2018 00:00:00'
INVOICE_DATE <= '16 Dec 2018 00:00:00'
```

and I get this message:

> "The datediff function resulted in an overflow. The number of dateparts separating two date/time instances is too large. Try to use datediff with a less precise datepart."

How can I write it in a different way (or how can I use datediff here?) to get the result?

Comment: That `where` condition is invalid to begin with. I am surprised that you can even run that. I also don't see any `datediff()` in your query

Comment: Which datatype is INVOICE_HEADING .INVOICE_DATE?

Comment: Sorry, it is DATE

Comment: Where is DateDiff function in your sql query?

Comment: Yes, a typo there. select * from INVOICE_HEADING IH where 
IH.INVOICE_DATE >=  '06 Dec 2018 00:00:00'
AND IH.INVOICE_DATE <= '16 Dec 2018 00:00:00'

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  that's not the original query, you are right, the problem is in another place. Let me check

Comment: Then **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add the real query that results in the error. Do **not** post code in comments.

Comment: I've solved it, thanks!! the problem wasn't there it was a field with a date from '1899'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function [DATEDIFF](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) returns a signed integer, which can hold values from -2.147.483.648 to 2.147.483.647. If the dates you are applying the function to and the unit you are using (month, day, second, etc.) generate a difference outside these bounds then an error is thrown.

There are a few workarounds:

- Use [DATEDIFF_BIG](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-big-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) if you are using SQL Server 2016+.
- Move to a "higher" unit (milliseconds -> seconds -> minutes -> hours and so on) until the value you get can be cast into a integer and make sure that all the values you might apply the function to in the future will still be inside the bounds of an integer. You can then drill down the unit to the one you need by multiplying and handling the value as `BIGINT` (for example).
- It's common for this error to pop up when comparing dates that are not valid to the business or generated by default as `1900-01-01`. You can filter these with a `WHERE` clause, supply a decent default value or convert to `NULL`. Can also avoid applying the `DATEDIFF` function with a `CASE` before it when dates aren't reasonable.

Examples:

```
DECLARE @OldDate DATE = '1900-01-01'

DECLARE @Now DATE = GETDATE()

SELECT DATEDIFF(SECOND, @OldDate, @Now) AS DateDiffResult

--Msg 535, Level 16, State 0, Line 5
--The datediff function resulted in an overflow. The number of dateparts separating two date/time instances is too large. Try to use datediff with a less precise datepart.
```

Change the unit from second to minute:

```
DECLARE @OldDate DATE = '1900-01-01'

DECLARE @Now DATE = GETDATE()

SELECT DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @OldDate, @Now) AS DateDiffResult

-- DateDiffResult: 62599680
```

Revert the minute to second with a "bigger" data type:

```
DECLARE @OldDate DATE = '1900-01-01'

DECLARE @Now DATE = GETDATE()

SELECT 
    CONVERT(BIGINT, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @OldDate, @Now)) * 60 AS DateDiffResult

-- DateDiffResult: 3755980800
```